# how can i call the file testo.txt, directly from the function argument? what's a more pythonic way?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, arguments, spyder

```
path='/home/quattro/file python /L9/files/'
testo=open(path+'testo.txt', encoding='utf8')
def clines(file, s):
    cnt=0
    with file as f:
        for i in f:
            cnt+=1
        return cnt
print(clines(testo, 'err'))
```

if i just put as argument 'testo.txt' id throw me:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'testo.txt'
```

what is a more global solution, without having to do the whole assignment of path?

bonus question: where can i learn to be more pitonic in my programming without spamming questions like that in stack overflow?
Thank you

bonus question: where can i learn to be more pitonic in my programming without spamming questions like that in stack overflow?
Thank you

Comment: Why not `clines(path+'testo.txt')`? And you should open the file inside the function: `with open(file) as f:`...

Answer (score 0):

What is the space at end of folder name `'file python '`?

check first thet directory exists

```
path_exists = os.path.exists(path)
print(f"{path_exists=}")
```

as result

```
path_exists=True
```

then check path and file

```
file_exists = os.path.exists(path + file)
print(f"{file_exists=}")
```

and here

```
file_exists=False
```

to understand it is wrong path or file

and better to do in this way

```
path='/home/quattro/file python /L9/files/'

def count_lines(path_to_file):
    lines_counter = 0
    with open(path_to_file, encoding='utf8') as f:
        for i in f:
            lines_counter += 1
    return lines_counter

print(count_lines(path+'testo.txt'))
```

Comment: The path indeed exist, and the space at the end is just the name of the folder, but yeah I can see it could cause problems.
I tried removing the space, but same error.

Comment: maybe you reason in the access rights?

Comment: I checked and path exist, but file_exists=False.

I think maybe Ronin is right, I'm runing spyder in debian as a normal user, but it should still have the permission to read a file, right?

Comment: indeed path exists but you can make a mistake in path you described in variable `path`. with my code `path_exists` is `True` and `file_exists` is `False` right?

Comment: copy pasted, both your code, and the folder directory, I don't think I made a mistake.

Yes, correct: path exist True, and file exist False.

Comment: try to `sudo python my_code.py`

Comment: Same error :(, I don't want to bother you longer, is there any pointer you could give me to research this?

Comment: since I don't see it, i think about correct path, file_name and rights

Comment: ... and try to avoid spaces in folders and file names if it possible